# How many Ender Eyes do you need to activate the End portal?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I want to be prepped to fight the Ender Dragon, so how many Ender Pearls should I bring to activate the portal?

Answer (score 1):

To activate the End portal, you need 12 Ender Eyes. It could be the case that some Ender Eyes are already put in. You can't activate the End Portal with Ender Pearls.